# Unity is gone. All window buttons gone. how to fix it?

Tags: unity, 13.04

Today I logged in ubuntu and without me doing any changes to the system recently, unity is gone. I have no dash, i can't move around my windows. What I noticed is that e.g nautilus opens but there are no window frames/buttons. I found a relative question in the forums, tried the answer but nothing changed. Can someone help me fix or re-install unity?
Thanks in advance

Comment: sudo apt-get --purge unity & sudo apt-get install unity

Comment: I already tried that. It didn't fix it.

Comment: What happens when you try a different profile? Are the buttons present there?

Comment: It seems like [the solutions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) may fix this, as this is somewhat similar (except in your case you seem to have a way to *create* windows). If that doesn't work, perhaps the problem is more related to compiz and less to unity. In that case, what happens if you run `compiz --replace`? (You should be able to do that--if you can run programs, just without borders around their windows, then you should be able to open the Terminal.)

Comment: @Benk, I logged in as a guest but no improvements. I start thinking that it has something to do with graphics drivers? My laptop has 2 graphics cards from which one is not supported. Maybe it found beta drivers? I don't know.

Comment: @EliahKagan I tried that one as well. It didn't work either. It does seem like the same problem I'm having tho. What I noticed when i did that is: When I enabled the unity plugin, it checked the `OpenGL` checkbox, and instantly unchecked it. Like `OpenGL` couldn't be activated.

Comment: This seems more and more like the problem is that `compiz` (the window manager) is not working (or not running). I believe that would make it so many options in CCSM would behave this way. In other words, I think *this is not a problem with Unity itself*, but with Compiz (on which Unity relies). Your window borders are missing (those provide the ability to move, resize, and minimize windows, and provide a window's title bar), and window borders are provided by the window manager (which for a Unity desktop is Compiz). What text appears in the Terminal when you run `compiz --replace`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
    sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. As I said I found relative answers to this problem, yours was one of them. It didn't do it.